# --mapreduce-name not working with sqoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

When I tried to sqoop the data and in the query when I use
`--mapreduce-name` both in free form query as well as in normal import, sqoop is giving the generic name for the jar that is QueryResult.jar for free form query for Sqoop import it is giving the tablename as jar which is default.

Why `--mapreduce-name` is not reflecting. Could anyone help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-D mapred.job.name=customJobName` to set the name of the MR job Sqoop launches.

> if not specified, the name defaults to the jar name for the job -
>   which is derived from the used table name.

Comment: i think mapred.job.name is deprecated  . is equal as  --mapreduce-name the problem is even if I use -- mapreduce-name the job name is not getting reflected

Comment: The deprecation alternative is `mapreduce.job.name`. `--mapreduce-name` is not a valid sqoop command line argument. To pass Hadoop properties, use the `-D` flag with property as key-value.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop command syntax:

```
sqoop import [GENERIC-ARGS] [TOOL-ARGS]
```

AS per sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_using_generic_and_specific_arguments),

Use `-D mapred.job.name=<job_name>` to set the name of the MR job that Sqoop launches.

Sample command:

```
 sqoop import \
-D mapred.job.name=my_custom_name \
--connect 'jdbc:db2://192.xxx.xxx.xx:50000/BENCHDS' \
--driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver \
--username db2inst1 \
--password db2inst1 \
--table db2inst1.table1 \
--hive-import \
--hive-table hive_table1 \
--null-string '\\N' \
--null-non-string '\\N' \
--verbose
```